# Unprojecting a 2D point to 3D space on a plane with perspective.

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm not a good mathematician, but I'm trying to unproject 2D screen coordinates to a plane in a 3D space with perspective.

I first do an uniform scaling on the 3D scene. Then I rotate around X axis, the plane defined by X axis and Z axis. Then I translate the scene on Z axis, with a value of `-1.0`.

So I have a ProjectionView matrix, computed by the following way, using the library linmath.h, in language C:

```
mat4x4 ProjectionView, matrix;

mat4x4 projection;
mat4x4_identity(projection);
mat4x4_perspective(projection, fova, width/height, zNear, zFar);

mat4x4 view;
mat4x4_identity(view);
mat4x4_translate(view, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
mat4x4_rotate(matrix, view, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, theta);
mat4x4_scale_aniso(view, matrix, scale, scale, scale);

mat4x4_mul(ProjectionView, projection, view);
```

Here is the graphic I use to try to unproject:

[image]

The distance `Oz` is what I can compute using trigonometry, it is on the plane where are the unprojected points, but it doesn't take in consideration the effects of perspective.

So I would like to know how to correct this `Oz` distance, using the perspective parameters, in order to have the unprojected `z` coordinate ?

And then how to compute `x` coordinate, from the unprojected `z` and from the perspective parameters ?

After some readings on internet, I tried using the inverse ProjectionView matrix, or with the inverse Projection matrix, without a good result, maybe due to the fact I don't know the `z` value to give to these matrices. So I wonder if there is a way to solve this problem without using an inverse matrix ?

The computed `Oz` distance is close to the true result, I think it just need a correction due to the perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ProjectionView matrix $P$ maps the visible part of the 3D world (bounded by the view frustum and the near and far planes) to *normalized device coordinates*, a $2\times 2\times 2$ cube with the computer's screen (the near plane) at the $z=-1$ face.

So your first task is to convert the *screen* coordinates of the "clicked point" $(p_x, p_y)$ to normalized device coordinates. If your viewport has width $w$ and height $h$, this is 
$$n_x = \frac{2p_x}{w} -1, \qquad n_y = 1- \frac{2p_y}{h}, \qquad n_z = -1.$$

Now the perspective projection happens in *homogeneous coordinates*, so that if $\mathbf{q} = (q_x,q_y,q_z,1)$ is a point in world coordinates,
$$\left([P\mathbf{q}]_x/[P\mathbf{q}]_w, [P\mathbf{q}]_y/[P\mathbf{q}]_w, [P\mathbf{q}]_z/[P\mathbf{q}]_w, 1\right) = (n_x, n_y, n_z, 1)$$
is the corresponding projected point in normalized device coordinates. This mapping is not linear and cannot be inverted by taking $P^{-1}$; but notice that 
$$P\mathbf{q} = [P\mathbf{q}]_z \mathbf{n}.$$
and so $\mathbf{q} = (P^{-1}\mathbf{n}) / (P^{-1}\mathbf{n})_z.$

Of course, this is the clicked point's position in world coordinates, *not* the location of the projected point on the black plane. To find the position of the point on the plane, you could query the depth buffer and set $n_z$ to that depth; this approach is error-prone if the depth buffer lacks sufficient precision, though. Another approach is to simply shoot a ray from the eye through $\mathbf{q}$ and compute where it intersects the black plane.

Notice many possible places for subtle bugs in the above procedure: 1) trying to unproject the point from screen coordinates rather than NDC; 2) forgetting to flip the $y$-axis when converting to NDC; 3) setting $n_z$ to something other than $-1$; 4) forgetting to set $n_w$ to 1; 5) forgetting to divide the unprojected point by its new (non-1) $w$ coordinate; etc.

By the way, there are functions like `gluUnproject` that do most of the above for you---check your graphics library's documentation.